# LINQ-to-Entity Joined Table Return

Tags: entity-framework, join, linq-to-entities

I have two tables as follows:

```
Departments:
   DeptID   (PK)
   DeptName
   ...

Employees: 
   EmpID    (PK)
   DeptID   (FK)
   EmpName
   ...
```

and I have a query using LINQ as follows:

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployee(int deptID)
{
    var query = from e in mdc.Employees
                join d in mdc.Departments on e.DeptID equals d.DeptID
                where e.DeptID == deptID
                select new { e.EmpID, e.EmpName, d.DeptName };

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Now my question is this. I would like to select the fields EmpID, EmpName, and DeptName.
But what will my return type be? This one returns an error because this query returns a `GenericList` as opposed to my `List<Employee>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create another class with required properties like this,

```
public class NewType{
public EmpID{get;set;}
//other fields here
}
```

and then select ,

```
public List<NewType> GetEmployee(int deptID)
{
    var query = from e in mdc.Employees
                join d in mdc.Departments on e.DeptID equals d.DeptID
                where e.DeptID == deptID
                select new NewType{ e.EmpID, e.EmpName, d.DeptName };

    return query.ToList();
}
```